# O 4 other users, who art ye?

Tags: feature-request, chat, ping

When starting to ping someone in chat there appears some user boxes that you can click on or tab key to select that user to ping. When there are many *n* number of users that match your ping search it creates a box that says *(and n more matches)*.

- could this be changed to say *"and n more users"*
- can you make that box clickable/selectable. So that when you select it, it opens up the rest of the users that match your search. Similar to how this already happens when you click on that half circular arrow thing to see all users in the room when there are *x* number of users in the room instead of only seeing like the first 3 rows of users.

[image: chat-image-example]

Comment: they are [Tim](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132562/165773)

Comment: Agree about "users" instead of "matches", but IMO not worth spending much time on implementing your second suggestion. Just narrow the search by typing more letters.

Comment: The question title with its wrong singular form is annoying.

Comment: @chirlu Better?

Comment: @James: Good attempt, but … the correct archaic form really would be “who are you”. :) (_Art_ is a second-person singular verb, _ye_ is to _you_ as _him_ is to _he_.) I’m hesitating to make that edit; but perhaps I should be more bold.

Comment: Pretty sure you mean "who are ye" :)

Comment: If you saw that many options after typing 5 or 6 letters, I'd think this was a reasonable request...but you've only typed 1 letter. As Shadow Wizard said, you should just narrow down the search by typing more letters - it's almost certainly faster than type, click to expand, scan through suggestions, click the one you want, click back into the text field to continue typing. In your example, if you typed even one more letter, you'd get rid of most of the suggestions